# NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData fails with binary plist

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, macos, plist

### Update: solved. code updated.

I'm working on some code to process plists in Objective-C++.

When I pass the function a path to an XML plist, everything works swimmingly and the output says:

```
2014-08-12 17:06:47.932 plist_tests[96368:507] plist was in xml format
```

When I pass the function a path to a binary plist, I get the following error:

```
2014-08-12 17:02:23.598 plist_tests[95709:507] could not deserialize plist: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." (Unexpected character b at line 1) UserInfo=0x7f9f2040cd60 {NSDebugDescription=Unexpected character b at line 1, kCFPropertyListOldStyleParsingError=The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.}
```

Here's the code. Note that I can't use `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` for my use-case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

class Status {
public:
  Status(int c, std::string m) : code_(c), message_(m) {}
public:
  int getCode() { return code_; }
  std::string getMessage() { return message_; }
  bool ok() { return getCode() == 0; }
  std::string toString() { return getMessage(); }
private:
    int code_;
    std::string message_;
};

Status readFile(const std::string& path, std::string& content) {
  if (!boost::filesystem::exists(path)) {
    return Status(1, "File not found");
  }

  std::ifstream file_h(path);
  if (file_h) {
     file_h.seekg (0, file_h.end);
     int len = file_h.tellg();
     file_h.seekg (0, file_h.beg);
     char *buffer = new char [len];
     file_h.read(buffer, len);
     if (!file_h) {
      return Status(1, "Could not entire file");
     }
     content.assign(buffer, len);
  } else {
    return Status(1, "Could not open file for reading");
  }

  return Status(0, "OK");
}

void parsePlist(const std::string& path) {
  std::string file_content;
  Status readFileStatus = readFile(path, file_content);
  if (!readFileStatus.ok()) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't read file");
    return;
  }
  NSData *plist_content = [NSData dataWithBytes:file_content.c_str()
                                         length:file_content.size()];

  NSError *error;
  NSPropertyListFormat plist_format;
  id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plist_content
                                                       options:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                        format:&plist_format
                                                         error:&error];

  if (plist == nil) {
    NSLog(@"could not deserialize plist: %@", error);
  } else {
    switch (plist_format) {
    case NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat:
      NSLog(@"plist was in openstep format");
      break;
    case NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0:
      NSLog(@"plist was in xml format");
      break;
    case NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0:
      NSLog(@"plist was in binary format");
      break;
    default:
      NSLog(@"plist was in unknown format");
      break;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    std::cout << "Usage: plist <filename>" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  parsePlist(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

To compile: `g++ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lglog -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation plist.mm -o plist`

The reason why I'm head scratching is because if I do a `plutil -convert xml1 file.plist -o -` on the binary plist, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you convert the data to an `NSString` and then to `NSData` is somewhat bad for XML and very bad for binary data.  Instead do this:

```
NSData *plist_content = [NSData dataWithBytes: file_content.c_str()
                                length: file_content.size() ];
```

There is also a problem with your `readFile` function.  Consider the line

```
content = std::string(buffer);
```

How does std::string know the length of the buffer?  It looks for a NUL byte, but that is the wrong thing to do with binary data.  You could replace that line with

```
content.assign( buffer, len );
```

Or if your path is an absolute path, you can get rid of `readFile` and say

```
NSData *plist_content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:
                                [NSString stringWithUTF8String: path.c_str() ];
```

Comment: +1, no need to go to an `NSString` as an intermediary.

Comment: Although a much better idea, changing the way plist_content gets populated doesn't solve the issue :/ the error is still the same.

Comment: @marpaia, I assume that `readFile` is your code too, but you didn't show it to us.  Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: @JWWalker you're a god among mere mortals, thank you.